# Word Wrapping UITabBarItem's Label (Objective C)

Tags: uitabbar, word-wrap, uitabbaritem

I've looked into TitleTextAttributes and tried using NSLineBreakMode, but I get errors no matter what I try. Surely someone has figured out how to simply word wrap the label of a tabbaritem - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using the UITabBarContoller it is not possible, you need to create your own custom control